# GGeffects on faceted ggplot2 giving: Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I'm trying to plot the predictions using `ggeffects`. The plot uses raw data paired with predictions, faceted according to `species`.

I get error `Error in geom_ribbon():mapping must be created by aes()`

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(xaxis = rnorm(300, 2, 3), yaxis = rnorm(300,8,3), rfactor = rep(c("A","B","C"), times = 100), species = rep(c("AA","BB"), each = 150))

fit <- lmer(yaxis ~ xaxis + species + (1|rfactor), data= df)
pred1 <- ggpredict(fit, c("xaxis", "species")) 

pred1 <- data.frame(pred1)

ggplot(df, aes(x= xaxis, y= yaxis, color = species, group = species)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~species) + 
  geom_ribbon(pred1, aes(x= xaxis, ymin= conf.low, ymax= conf.high, group = species ), fill= 'grey80',inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_line(pred1, aes(x= xaxis, y= predicted, , group = species ),inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, the first argument of all `geom_`s is the `mapping=`, whereas `data=` is the second. Hence, when you pass a dataframe to a `geom` as the first argument you have to name the argument using `data=`. Second, in the dataframe returned by `ggpredict` the original names get dropped. So you have to `rename` the columns to make your code and especially the facetting work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

pred1 <- dplyr::rename(pred1, xaxis = x, species = group)

ggplot(df, aes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis, color = species, group = species)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ species) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = pred1,
    aes(x = xaxis, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, group = species),
    fill = "grey80", inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = pred1,
    aes(x = xaxis, y = predicted, group = species),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh! Gotcha!! Thank you. That makes so much more sense. A side note: Do you know how to add the equations and R2 from the model fit using `ggeffects` for facet? I can't seem to find good documentation on SO

Comment: Unfortunately no. Did some googling myself but couldn't find an easy out-of-the-box option to achieve that. :(